# iPhone iOS how to create graphics effects like drop shadow, etc? What effects are built-into iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I apologize for a large set of questions here. 
I'm starting to play with Quartz Graphics more and more, and found that it has interesting effects, yet I do not have many samples to see them in action.

```
 view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
```

There's a shadow property:

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 9;
```

I was unable to make the shadow show though.

Borders:

```
 view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
   view.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

**What other effects can I get from built-in iOS on iPhone?** **Is there a comprehensive demo project that can showcase what kind of graphic manipulation functionality is built into iOS?**

How do I do transparency masking?

Is there a way to add inner shadow or inner glow?
Is there a way to make an iOS button appear more "concave" than it really is?

Is there a way to do radial gradients?
Is there a way to create multi-ray lens flare effects like Adobe Illustrator? 
Is there a way to blend layers using "lighten, dissolve", or other photoshop effects?
Is there a way to dynamically adjust the brightness of the image? I know how to do hue shift.

I would appreciate any other hints on what kind of layer effects I can apply to the CALayers

Comment: I'll answer your first question: You need to set the view.layer.maskToBounds = NO; to show the shadow

Comment: Thanks! I'm using masks to bounds to show rounded corners. This makes me believe that rounded corners and shadow are not compatible, unless I create my view from two views and somehow manipulate paths

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What an interesting coincidence! I've just recently held a presentation at an *iOS Game Design Seminar* on **CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation** and just today I've published some of the documents on Github.

So if you prefer some hands on examples you can check out the repository here: https://github.com/pkluz/PKCoreTechniques

Includes some of the following examples:

- Color Fill
- Gradient Fill (Linear and Radial)
- Simple Paths
- Bezier Curves
- Clipping (Standard and Even-Odd)
- Creating custom-drawn Buttons
- Simple Translations
- Translations with Hit-Test Triggers
- A very primitive 'CoverFlow' with 3D Transformations in CoreAnimation.

.. and some more ;-)

Hope you find what you need, but from what I see it should cover a fair amount of what you've requested.

*Note*: There's also a PDF that serves as an interactive tutorial.

Comment: This is beyond great. This is simply awesome example! I see that the angry bird paths are hard-coded in. Did you type them in or use some form of code generation tool?  Do you know if it's possible to get points for this path from a graphics editor, like adobe illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really good [tutorial](http://d3signerd.com/deep-dive-into-calayer-shadows/), it helped me a lot, maybe it'll help you too.

Comment: Thanks for a great shadow example, this is very much what I've been looking for!

Comment: @Templar, your given link out dated now.

Comment: @iAmbitious Yeah, it looks like the page isn't available anymore. [This](http://d3signerd.com/old/deep-dive-into-calayer-shadows/) is a cached-like version, but the images are missing :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation of a radial gradient generation using CIImage. It displays the named image if a gradient was not created. Otherwise it displays a radial gradient.

```
+(UIImage*)doRadialGradientFilter:(NSString*)baseImageName 
{

    CIFilter* controlsFilter  = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIRadialGradient" keysAndValues:
                   @"inputColor1", [CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0
                                                    blue:0.0 alpha:0.0], @"inputColor0", [CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0
                                                                                                          blue:0.5 alpha:0.5], @"inputRadius0", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0], nil];


    CIImage *displayImage = controlsFilter.outputImage;
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:displayImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    if (displayImage == nil || finalImage == nil) {
        // We did not get output image. Let's display the original image itself.
        return  [UIImage imageNamed:baseImageName];
    }else {
        // We got output image. Display it.
        return  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:displayImage fromRect:displayImage.extent]];
    }

}
```